# Problems unsolvable by an oracle machine?

Tags: complexity-classes, computability

Are there classes of problems that cannot be solved by an oracle machine? If so, are there specific problem examples of that class of problems?

Even the Omega number, at least the first N digits, could be computed as the Oracle could just return TRUE or FALSE for each {0,1}-digits...